# I have a python dataframe, I like to export to an excel file with a certain keyword to be set to highlighted by setting color to red (not entire cell)

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pandas-styles

I have a python DataFrame, I like to export to an excel file with a certain keyword to be set to highlighted by setting color to `red` (*not the entire cell that contains the keyword*).

For example:

```
SR_Id   SR_Desc
13835   VM Backup failed ...
38923   Password out of sync ...
38928   vCenter Restore slow ...
82832   Unable to login with root Password
```

What I want to do is to be able to export this df to an `Excel` file and set ONLY `"Password"` keyword on column `SR_Desc` to be Red color like this :

[image]